# Does Unix SCP command continues to copy files althouth the response code is > 0

Tags: file-copy

There was a case where an scp command returned response code > 0 but the files where successfully copied and finally loaded in a db which means that they were not corrupted.

Does Unix SCP command continues to copy files althouth the response code is > 0? If resp > 0 the files should the files be corrupted or not even transfered at all? I expected that a resp > 0 means the copy is stopped without any files copied.

Code used:

```
scp -r [!.]* user@172.0.0.1:/home/user/DATA_* /app/data
if (($? > 0)); then touch conn_error_172_0_0_1.bad; fi
```

According to this manual the response codes > 0 are errors http://support.microfocus.com/kb/doc.php?id=7021696 –

Answer (score 0):

> Does Unix SCP command continues to copy files althouth the response code is > 0

That question doesn't make sense – it's `scp` which returns that code, and it only returns when it's done doing whatever it does. So, at the point you get a return code, `scp` is done. Nothing happens after. There's no scp to continue doing anything!

Whether or not `scp` was able to copy no files, all files, or just some files, that depends on the error (and the point at which it occurred).

If you need your copies to be atomic, use `rsync` with the `--delay-updates` option instead of `scp`.

Comment: Sorry for my bad english. The point is that scp returns an error code and I expect that files are not copied at all. So, which response codes stop the copy and which let the copy continue/finish?

Comment: none. As said, that depends on which error occurs *when*. You cannot infer from the error code whether a partial transfer happened or not, in general. So, I recommended an alternative to `scp` in my answer's last paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for `scp` states,

> The `scp` utility exits 0 on success, and >0 if an error occurs.

This is not particularly precise so we need to try an experiment:

```
scp remoteHost:/etc/no_such_file /tmp; echo SS=$?    # "SS=1"
scp remoteHost:/etc/hosts /tmp; echo SS=$?           # "SS=0"
scp no_such_host:/etc/hosts /tmp; echo SS=$?         # "SS=255"
```

Now let's look at a combination:

```
scp remoteHost:/etc/no_such_file remoteHost:/etc/hosts /tmp; echo SS=$?    # "SS=1"
```

Note here that although the exit status was non-zero, the file `/etc/hosts` was successfully copied. I imagine this is your situation, where some files were copied and others were not.

The exit status is the same for each situation whether or not `-O` (force `scp` protocol rather than new default `sftp` protocol) is used.

The conclusion I would draw is simply that of the documentation, that an error of some sort occurred if the exit status is non-zero, and no error occurred for any transfer if the exit status was zero.

Comment: This is close to my case. Script connects to 5 servers and downloads files (1 or 2 per server). We got errors for all 5 connection attempts and finally 7 of 8 files which were not corrupted and were successfully loaded in database. But we got 5 errors although the in some servers all files were successfully downloaded. I just added an exit if an error comes up and log the error.